# How to make webpage a one time visit? E.g. Not being able to return to a link once visited

Tags: html, css, paypal

My question is regarding the PayPal commerce system, where you can sell items such an an eBook in my case.
However if you see the image below:
[IMG of download link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9StR4.png)

Once paid, the buyer is then directed to the eBook download link (hosted on my WebServer), my question is, whats to stop people just remembering the download link and just stealing the ebook?
And how can i prevent this?

Thanks

Comment: Just like in your image, why not have the eBook emailed to the Paypal email address? Then you just have to redirect the user to a page that shows "Purchase successful" message (like in the page suggested example). This way the user will get the eBook as an attachment to the email but will in no case know the link to the original file on your server.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");<script>` should work

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.